# ¿Cómo hacer like con linq to sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo que obtener unos registros donde por eejeplo el parámetro puede ser:

***2020_123B

2020_123C

2020_123F

2020_123xxx***

Construí esta consulta pero me imagino que se puede optimizar:

```
var solicitud = (from s in db.A_CC_Solicitud
                         where s.IdSolicitud == id
                         || s.IdSolicitud.Contains(id)
                         || s.IdSolicitud.ToUpper() == id + "B"
                         || s.IdSolicitud.ToUpper() == id + "C"
                         || s.IdSolicitud.ToUpper() == id + "D"
                         || s.IdSolicitud.ToUpper() == id + "E"
                         || s.IdSolicitud.ToUpper() == id + "F"
                         || s.IdSolicitud.ToUpper() == id + "G"
                         && s.IdEstado >= 55 && s.IdEstado < 60
```

Comment: El "sustituto" de like sería `Contains`...pero ya veo que lo usas en `s.IdSolicitud.Contains(id)`...con lo que no entiendo tu duda. A no ser que quieras especificamente filtrar que acabe en `B`,`C`, etc..

Comment: Pero cuando hago el contains , no me trae las demas por ejemplo si paso 2020_123A me devuelve   2020_123; 2020_123A .... pero no por ejemplo 2020_123C

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia para Contains entre 2020_123A y 2020_123C. Asi que es posible que el dato que estas recibiendo no sea ese. De todas formas, dado que es el inicio lo que es siempre igual, puedes usar tambien `StartsWith`

Comment: [Aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SfJX4Q) tienes un fiddle que demuestra que contains devuelve todos los resultados.

Comment: Si  paso como parametro 2020_123 me de vuelve bien ...pero si paso como parametro 2020_123B   no me devuelve  2020_123C , 2020_123 D por ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer si se puede simplificar solo utilizando contains:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> ids = new List<string>();
    ids.Add("qwerf2020_123");
    ids.Add("2020_123qwer");
    ids.Add("2020_123A");
    ids.Add("2020_123B");
    ids.Add("2020_123C");
    ids.Add("2020_123D");
    ids.Add("2020_123E");
    ids.Add("2020_123F");
    ids.Add("2020_123G");
    ids.Add("2021_123G2");
    ids.Add("2021_1231");
    ids.Add("2021_12312");
    ids.Add("2021_123123");
    ids.Add("2021_1231234");

    
    PrintList("Original", ids);

    string id = "2020_123";
    var filtrado = ids.Where(x => x.Contains(id)).ToList();

    PrintList($"Filtrado por: {id}", filtrado);

}

private static void PrintList<T>(string title, List<T> list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
    Console.WriteLine(title);
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
}
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]